# Timber package doesn't exist Error when generating signed apk and proguard is activated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk, timber-android

I'm trying to generate a signed apk with android studio, it gives me these errors

```
Error:(59, 18) error: package timber.log does not exist
Error:(27, 23) error: package okhttp3.logging does not exist
```

in my application class I define Timber as follow

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
} else {
    Timber.plant(new CrashReportingTree());
}
```

and this is the Okhttp logging method I use:

```
public static HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
return new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY :HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
}
```

gradle setup as follow:

```
 release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

and there is no specific proguard configurations. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem that causing this issue, in build.gradle app module file I was choosing the `debugCompile` instead of the regular `compile`so instead of

```
  debugCompile  "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$TIMBER_VERSION"
```

I should use this line

```
  compile  "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$TIMBER_VERSION"
```

and the same for `okhttp3:logging-interceptor`, after correcting the previous lines, and writing some proguard rules, I've generated the signed apk.